# How to use own algorithm to extract features in scikit-learn ( text feature extraction)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to use my own algorithm to extract features from training data and then  fit and transform using `CountVectorize` in `scikit-learn`.

Currently I am doing:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cvect_obj = CountVectorizer()
vects = cvect_obj.fit_transform(traning_data)
```

`fit_transform(traning_data)`automatically extracts features and transforms it, but I want to use my own algorithm to extract features.

Comment: Can you say more about the algorithm you wish to use to extract features, and the way you wish to use those features? What's the machine learning task you wish to accomplish?

Comment: @duhaime currently i am working review categorization either positive or negative . using uni gram modeling i got 77% accuracy on test data . But i want to extract only bi-gram phrases and uni-gram sentiment words after doing pos tagging and use extracted phrases and sentiment words as features .

Comment: Probably you should generate some sparse matrices and then work with that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is quite not possible using it directly though.As a rule by scikit-learn they only add well-established algorithms. A rule of thumb is at least 3 years since publications, 200+ citations and wide use and usefullness. A technique that provides a clear-cut improvement (e.g. an enhanced data structure or efficient approximation) on a widely-used method will also be considered for inclusion.

Moreover, your implementation doesn’t need to be in scikit-learn to be used together with scikit-learn tools, though. Implement your favorite algorithm in a scikit-learn compatible way, upload it to github and it will be listed under Related Projects.

Answer (score 1):

As you can't alter the sklearn core, you can always keep your own feature extractions. All you have to make sure is that most of the numeric modules in sklearn deals with sparse matrix, like scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.

All you need is a method or a module that takes a data in raw form (say, a sentence), and convert it into a sparse matrix. A basic skeleton I would write would be:

```
class MyFeatureExtractor:
  def __init__():
    dictionary = {}
    vocab = []

  def fit(list of sentences):
    # learn the words after basic nlp pipeline
    # build dictionary/map between word and feature index

  def transform(new sentences):
    # for each sentence, build a sparse vector of length equal to 
    # your vocabulary, or size of dictionary
    # return the matrix
```

Now you can use your FeatureExtractor to transform just like regular sklearn modules.